# android parsing json object to listview

Tags: android, json

Finally i give up, and i need your help guys,
i have a simple problem,

i have a great tutorial from this link : 
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-json-parsing-with-jsonobject-and-loading-to-listview-example/

in that tutorial use json array of object like this :

```
"{ " +        
                " \"countries\":[ " +

                    "{" +
                        "\"countryname\": \"India\","+
                        "\"flag\": "+ R.drawable.india + ","+
                        "\"language\": \"Hindi\","+
                        "\"capital\": \"New Delhi\"," +
                        "\"currency\": {" +
                                        "\"code\": \"INR\", " + 
                                        "\"currencyname\": \"Rupee\" " +
                                    "}" + 
                    "}, " +

                    "{" +
                        "\"countryname\": \"Pakistan\","+
                        "\"flag\": "+ R.drawable.pakistan + ","+
                        "\"language\": \"Urdu\","+
                        "\"capital\": \"Islamabad\"," +                         
                        "\"currency\": {" +
                                        "\"code\": \"PKR\", " + 
                                        "\"currencyname\": \"Pakistani Rupee\" " +
                                    "}" + 
                    "}," +

                    "{" +
                        "\"countryname\": \"Sri Lanka\","+
                        "\"flag\": "+ R.drawable.srilanka + ","+
                        "\"language\": \"Sinhala\","+
                        "\"capital\": \"Sri Jayawardenapura Kotte\"," +                         
                        "\"currency\": {" +
                                        "\"code\": \"SKR\", " + 
                                        "\"currencyname\": \"Sri Lankan Rupee\" " +
                                    "}" + 
                    "}" +   

                "]" + 
            "} "
```

nah my problem is, i only to need parse this simple json

```
"{ " +        
                " \"countries\": " +

                    "{" +
                        "\"countryname\": \"India\","+
                        "\"flag\": "+ R.drawable.india + ","+
                        "\"language\": \"Hindi\","+
                        "\"capital\": \"New Delhi\"," +
                        "\"currency\": {" +
                                        "\"code\": \"INR\", " + 
                                        "\"currencyname\": \"Rupee\" " +
                    "}" + 

            "} "
```

that is only jsonobject, where must i change the code?

Comment: "that is only `jsonobject`, **where must i change the code?**" | What code? please show your code, how to parse it, and please post the logcat. My guess is that you had errors in `R.drawable.india`. do you have `R.drawable.india` inside your `drawable` folder?

Answer (score 0):

you have make changes in this ListViewLoaderTask.. maybe u r getting error while returning the adapter as it does'nt contain any list.

```
    {
"id": 912345678902,
"text": "@android_newb just use android.util.JsonReader!",
"geo": [
    50.454722,
    -104.606667
],
"user": {
    "name": "jesse",
    "followers_count": 2
}
```

}

```
[{
"id": 912345678902,
"text": "@android_newb just use android.util.JsonReader!",
"geo": [
    50.454722,
    -104.606667
],
"user": {
    "name": "jesse",
    "followers_count": 2
}
```

}]

```
String strJson =
            "{ " +
                " \"countries\":[ " +

                    "{" +
                        "\"countryname\": \"India\","+
                        "\"flag\": "+ R.drawable.india + ","+
                        "\"language\": \"Hindi\","+
                        "\"capital\": \"New Delhi\"," +
                        "\"currency\": {" +
                            "\"code\": \"INR\", " +
                            "\"currencyname\": \"Rupee\" " +
                        "}" +
                    "}, " +
                "]" +
            "} ";
```